# google-script throwing an error when deleting a row in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my very first day messing around with google script so excuse my limitations.

I was trying to write a function that deleted all the rows in a Form Spreadsheet while leaving the header row behind.

Why does this work:

```
  // Loop through the data in the range and delete the rows
if (data.length > 1) {
  for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
    ws.deleteRow(row+1);
    }
    ws.deleteRow(2); 

 }
```

While the following:

```
if (data.length > 1) {
  for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
    ws.deleteRow(row+1);
    }

  }
```

Leaves row 2 behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the row indexes are 1-based (i.e., start at 1), you need to alter your for loop like this:

```
for (var row = 1; row <= data.length; row++) {
```

Assuming you have 2 rows, when you hit your second row in the loop (that is, when row = 2), the value of `row` will not be less than `data.length` (which is `2`); it will be *equal* to the `data.length`.  So with `<`, the test will fail and the code in the loop will not be executed that second time.  With `<=` it will pass and code will be executed as desired.

This same pattern will of course happen with any number of rows.

EDIT:  a few other problems:

Because the removal will happen immediately, the rows will all shift after a removal and will be numbered differently.  This can be handled in a couple ways, but here's one: change your deletion to start from the end and work backwards.  so, now we have:

```
for (var row = data.length; row >= 1; row--) {
```

Also, if you're only trying to skip the first row, as the header row, rather that change the index used (e.g., `row + 1`), just change where you start/stop your loop.  this is simpler and more understandable.  so, the loop becomes:

```
 for (var row = data.length; row >= 2; row--) {
    ws.deleteRow(row);
 }
```

Comment: It works for the case when there are exactly 2 rows. However, if I add a third, row 2 is still not deleted without the extra line.

Comment: OK That fixed it thank you. I didn't realize it reordered the rows as it went.